# Cannot set property 'students' of undefined angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set ClassesServices to classes array.

And then, I add students of the class to new property, classes.students but It landed as Cannot set property 'students' of undefined.

```
$scope.classes = [];
$scope.getClasses = function(){
            ClassesServices.all().then(function(data){
                $scope.classes = data;
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.classes.length; i++){
                    ClassesServices.getStudentsbyClassId($scope.classes[i].id).then(function(data){
                        $scope.classes[i].students = data;
                    });
                } 
            });
        };

        $scope.getClasses();
```

Appreciate to any helps.

I wish to create separate function to add students but I got underfined. So I am not so sure it can be use separate function as below.

```
$scope.getClasses = function(){
            ClassesServices.all().then(function(data){
                $scope.classes = data;
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.classes.length; i++){
                        $scope.getStudentsbyClassId($scope.classes[i].students, $scope.classes[i].id);
                    });
                } 
            });
        };

$scope.getStudentsbyClassId = function (students){
    ClassesServices.getStudentsbyClassId(id).then(function(data){
        students = data;
};
        $scope.getClasses();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a number of issues here.

First, in your first example you are defining a function in a loop - [this will not produce the results you expect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake).

Second, you have some confusion in the second approach - you are passing `.students`, which at that time is `undefined`, to `$scope.getStudentsbyClassId` expecting this function to the property inside the array - that wouldn't work like that.

I recommend to get the promises of `getStudentsbyClassId` and execute a `$q.all`.

(And, by the way, unless you intend to invoke a function from the View, there is no need to define it on the $scope)

```
$scope.classes = [];
ClassesServices.all()
  .then(function(classesData){
     $scope.classes = classesData;

     var promisesForStudents = [];
     for(var i = 0; i < $scope.classes.length; i++){
       var classId = $scope.classes[i].id;
       promisesForStudent[i] = ClassesServices.getStudentsbyClassId(classId);
     }

     return $q.all(promisesForStudents);
  })
  .then(function(studentsData){
     for(var i = 0; i < studentsData.length; i++){
        $scope.classes[i].students = studentsData[i];
     }
  })
```

Comment: Thank New Dev. I have never thought to use nested promise service. It is far more useful than a single solution. Thank for your extra $scope suggestion. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Classes to classes in all the places you have "Classes". Objects and variables names are case-sensitive. So you are refering two diferents objects.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why?

Comment: Because Classes dont refer to the same variable of classes. The name of the variables are case-sensitive. You are refering to diferent variables. Sorry for mi bad english.

Comment: Add those details to your answer, not to the comments.

Comment: Sorry. My typing error. I just updated. just `$scope.classes`. Not Classes. Classes is `ClassesServices`. Just typo. Sorry. I don't get solution yet. Still underfined property

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing $scope.classes and $scope.Classes.  In angular capitalization matters.  If you change your references from $scope.Classes to $scope.classes you should be all set.

Comment: Sorry. My typing error. I just updated. just `$scope.classes`. Not Classes. Classes is `ClassesServices`. Just typo. Sorry. I don't get solution yet. Still underfined property